# robotframework- unable to click a button on a modal dialogue box

Tags: selenium, robotframework

when I open a particular webpage it has a EULA form that appears on top of the home page in the form of a modal in HTML/CSS. I have tried the XPath of the accept button but it says element not found also tried using handle alert.
is there a unique way to handle a dialogue box in robotframework?
[image of HTML in inspect view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTS9d.png)

Comment: What's the webpage?

Comment: Can you please paste the image of dialog box and html code, so that we can help you

Comment: sorry for the delay I have added an image of the inspect view of the webpage, (it's a beta site of a company I'm interning at )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SeleniumLibrary.Set Focus To Element    ${button_on_popup_page}
SeleniumLibrary.Click Element    ${button_on_popup_page}
```

I figured it out, shown in the above code. I first set focus to the button and then used the click element. This seemed to work.